# Web Scraping - Multiple Tables in popup windows

Tags: python, web-scraping

If I wanted to pull scores for a bunch of different teams from this site - would I be able to write some python code to do it - even thought the scores only show up when you click into the team and click on past schedule?

Is there a relatively simple way to do this?

https://results.advancedeventsystems.com/event/PTAwMDAwMjUxNTI90/divisions/111931/standings/-65298

Answer (score 0):

If the data is all on one page, you can scrape the HTML and get the information you need, pretty easily.

However, if you are trying to grab more than one page of data; it looks like this website is utilizing a database and pulling new information and parsing it to the webpage depending on what you click, that would be a bit more work.

You would need to call different parts of the website and then scrape each one into your python application and then you can manipulate the data anyway you choose after that point.

However, if you are simple trying to get it from that one page, you could absolute do that with a web scraper.